# javascript events and frameworks

Tags: javascript, events

This may seem silly to many out there, but I'd like to know if deep down ALL events and event listeners that you build in the javascript frameworks (angular, backbone)are tied to the built in events of the browser and no more?

Comment: depends on what events you are talking about. :)

Comment: No, the browser has no native event for something changing in a data model, as it does in Backbone.